# Почему я получаю ошибку "Ресурс не найден"?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Я новичок во флаттер и пуш уведомлениях
Сама ошибка - `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(INVALID_ICON, The resource  @mipmap/app_icon could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null, null)`

Кусочек кода, где я это использую - ```    AndroidInitializationSettings(' @mipmap/app_icon');

Фотография лежит в proj/app/src/main/res/drawable/app_icon.png

AndroidManifest -

```
<activity

            android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"` ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что иконки `mipmap` должны лежать в папке `mipmap`, а не в `drawable`.